# AutoHotKey script not recognizing Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, autohotkey

I've made a script that will set an environment variable to the path in the current Explorer windows when its hotkey is pressed. However, I want this to only trigger if the active window is an Explorer window. This should do it:

```
  #IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass|CabinetWClass
     #p::
        SetPath()
     return
  #IfWinActive
```

But for some reason it isn't. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Windows? XP, Vista, 7?

Comment: @iglvzx Sorry, Windows XP. Added that to the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe syntax [seems to be iffy](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic48542.html#294392). Use a [variant](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm#variant) instead:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class ExploreWClass
    #z::
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
    #z::
        MsgBox SetPath()
    return
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Perfect, that did it. Thanks! And that will still call SetPath if it's ExploreWClass?

Comment: Yes, they fall through until either the EOF or an `#IfWinActive` with no parameters.